# Android - Share Intent for ES File Explorer

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I want to create an app specifically aimed to launch the **ES File Explorer** Share by LAN intent. I have the latest **Manifest** for this app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    ... >
    <uses-permission 
        ... />
    <uses-feature
        ... />
    <uses-sdk
        ... />
    <supports-screens
        ... />
    <application
        ...
        android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.FexApplication"
        ... >
        ...
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973830"
            android:label="@2131427483"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.view.FileExplorerActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    android:mimeType="resource/folder"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="org.openintents.action.VIEW_DIRECTORY"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    android:scheme="file"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.estrongs.android.SHOW_DISK_USAGE"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.PopPreferenceActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.ESNetSettingActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.RecommAcitivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.RecommItemDetailAcitivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.RecommItemImageViewer"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@2131492869"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.OpenRecomm"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973835"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.ui.view.CreateOAuthNetDisk"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973835"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.ui.view.PcsThirdPartOAuth"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973835"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.ui.view.CreateOAuthServiceProvider"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973840"
            android:icon="@2130837715"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.compress.CompressionActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter
                android:label="@2131427488">
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973840"
            android:icon="@2130837715"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.compress.CompressionProxyActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter
                android:label="@2131427488">
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    android:mimeType="application/zip"/>
                <data
                    android:mimeType="application/x-rar-compressed"/>
                <data
                    android:mimeType="application/rar"/>
                <data
                    android:mimeType="application/x-gzip"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973840"
            android:icon="@2130837714"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.ESFileSharingActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter
                android:label="@2131427545">
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter
                android:label="@2131428206">
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter
                android:label="@2131428206">
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973830"
            android:label="@2131427545"
            android:icon="@2130837714"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.LocalFileSharingActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter
                android:label="@2131427545">
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973835"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.FileSharingNotificationActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity ...
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.PopVideoPlayer" ... >
            ... </activity>
        <activity ...
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.PopVideoPlayerProxyActivity"
            ... </activity>
        <activity ...
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.AudioPlayerProxyActivity"
            ... </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.StreamingMediaPlayer"
            ... />
        <service ... />
        <receiver ... </receiver>
        <activity
            ...
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.editor.PopNoteEditor"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
            <intent-filter
                android:label="@2131427486">
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    android:mimeType="text/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973836"
            android:label="@2131427486"
            android:icon="@2130837713"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.BTPopNoteEditor"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973839"
            android:label="@2131427483"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.FileChooserActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.estrongs.action.PICK_FILE"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    android:scheme="file"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.estrongs.action.PICK_FILE"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.estrongs.action.PICK_DIRECTORY"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    android:scheme="file"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.estrongs.action.PICK_DIRECTORY"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973839"
            android:label="@2131427483"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.ESContentChooserActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973839"
            android:label="@2131427483"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.ESRingtoneChooserActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.RINGTONE_PICKER"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973839"
            android:label="@2131427483"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.ESWallPaperChooserActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.imageviewer.CropImage"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>
        <activity
            android:label="@2131427487"
            android:icon="@2130837710"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.imageviewer.ViewImage21"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:label="@2131427487"
            android:icon="@2130837710"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.imageviewer.ViewImage"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:label="@2131427487"
            android:icon="@2130837710"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.ImageCommentActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustUnspecified"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.ImageCommentPostActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustResize"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.imageviewer.Wallpaper"/>
        <service
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.bt.OBEXFtpServerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.START_OBEX_FTP_SERVER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <provider
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.FileContentProvider"
            android:exported="true"
            android:authorities="com.estrongs.files"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973839"
            android:label="@2131427489"
            android:icon="@2130837709"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.DownloaderActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    ... />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    ... />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973839"
            android:label="@2131427489"
            android:icon="@2130837709"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.BrowserDownloaderActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    ... />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                     ... />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@2131427487"
            android:icon="@2130837710"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.PopRemoteImageBrowser"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter
                android:label="@2131427487">
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                    android:mimeType="image/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973830"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.ui.theme.ThemeActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973830"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.ui.theme.ModifyThemeActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973830"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.ui.theme.ThemeColorActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973830"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.ui.theme.ThemeFolderActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973830"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.network.EsNetworkActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@2131492874"
            android:label="@2131427483"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.ftp.ESFtpShortcut"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.ftp.ESFtpService"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.ui.preference.FtpServerPreference"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973909"
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.ShowDialogActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.HelpActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.PrivacyActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <service
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.ui.notification.ESTaskService"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.baidu.share.message.ShareReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="baidu.intent.action.PCS_SHARE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.pop.EnableOEMConfig">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED"/>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL"/>
                <data
                    android:scheme="file"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name="com.estrongs.android.ui.preference.TabletSettingsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973830"
            android:label="@2131427484"
            android:name=".app.PopAudioPlayer"
            android:launchMode="multiple"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973830"
            android:name=".app.GestureManageActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973830"
            android:name=".app.HideListActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973830"
            android:name="com.baidu.sapi2.utils.LoginProtectAcitivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan"/>
        <receiver
            android:name=".app.InstallMonitorReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
                <data
                    android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:theme="@16973840"
            android:name=".app.InstallMonitorActivity"
            android:taskAffinity="com.estrongs.android.pop.app.InstallMonitorActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Looking at this Manifest, is there a way I can send to ES File Explorer an intent with a "file path" which will trigger the Send by LAN feature?

Note: I want to create this app as the app's built in "Share by LAN" feature in the "Share via" dialogs is broken, see this [link for the full description of this bug](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59913/es-file-explorer-share-by-lan). (I've reported it to developer)

**UPDATE**

I got a response from the ES File Explorer developer team, they said that the "Share by LAN" feature in the "Share via" menu is not as we think it. This feature is only for sending files from Device to Device which both have ES File Explorer open and running on the same network, **not** for sending files to the PC (although I have requested this new feature as it would be most helpful).

Comment: Did you really need to post the entire 774-line XML to ask your question?  More detail is usually better than too little here, but your question was automatically flagged up for length. You may want to summarise the XML to avoid the risk of your (perfectly valid) question being closed.

Comment: I've never worked with Intent Filters, I didn't know what's important.

Comment: If there is a bug in ES File Explorer, why do you want to use it?

Comment: I was hoping that I could bypass the bug by calling an Intent, but it seems unlikely. I've reported the bug hopefully it will be sorted soon.

Comment: I have received a response from the ES File Explorer developer. Please see the main post above for full details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("*/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
shareIntent.setPackage("com.estrongs.android.pop");

startActivity(shareIntent);
```